# jquery .on() not finding click

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
// 3 lines other code here
<a hef="#" id="agreelink"><input id="agree" name="agree" value="Agree" style="position:relataive;border-style:none" /></a>
<input id="disagree" name="disagree" value="Disagree" style="position:relataive;border-style:none" />
<input id="abstain" name="abstain" value="Abstain" style="position:relataive;border-style:none" />
// 2 more lines here
</div>
```

I then have a function where i was using `.live()` as the elements are dynamic and it kept duplicating the fire, and I need to move to `.on()`.  So my function code I have tried to fire any of those buttons are as follows:

```
<$('#container').on('click', 'input', function() {
alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

and

```
<$('#container').on('click', '#agree', function() {
alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

and

```
<$('#container').on('click', 'a', function() {
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

But i cannot make it fire, I have searched online and tried and tested it, but I am sure I am not doing something right, just not sure what it is.  Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: First one works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jaW3F/. Is your jQuery inside a document ready call?

Comment: @j08691 Thank you, your help made me look much closer at what I was doing.
The issue was something stupid.   #container was also dynamic.  And `on()` needs to be on a static element. When i moved the div to a higher div which is built when the page it rendered, worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap them in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#container').on('click', 'input', function() 
    { 
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VVfUK/
I used `live()`, as it was your first choice, and used `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the `click` event from bubbling up.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks Sthe.  Good call.  But the issue was something stupid.   #container was also dynamic.  And `on()` needs to be on a static element. When i moved the div to a higher div was is built when the page it rendered, worked fine.  Thank you.

Comment: Owh. I see :-) I'm glad you found the solution.